# Why c programme code is not asking the second value & how come char is stored in int form I took this from an example on web

Tags: c, char

```
#include <stdio.h>
// source tutorial points
int main(){
    int c;
    char d;
    printf("Enter First value \n");

    c = getchar();

    printf("Enter Second value \n");
    d = getchar();

    printf("You have entered first \n");
    putchar(c);

    printf("You have entered second \n");
    putchar(d);

    return(0);
}
```

when I am entering first value it is not asking for other value please help I do not expect a character not possible in char.

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you are observing?
Are you never seeing "Enter Second value" message?
Can you give an example of output when running your program?

Comment: Because `'\n'` is a char...

Answer (score 3):

Because each time you input a character and hit ENTER. So, second `getchar` in your code reads the `enter` character.

Your code should change to:

```
    c = getchar();
    getchar(); // for consuming the enter character

    printf("Enter Second value \n");
    d = getchar();
    getchar(); // for consuming the enter character
```

The output:

```
Enter First value                                                                                                         
a                                                                                                                         
Enter Second value                                                                                                        
b                                                                                                                         
You have entered first                                                                                                    
a                                                                                                                         
You have entered second                                                                                                   
b
```